# How to change the MySQL Workbench editor background color?

Tags: mysql-workbench

How can I change the MySQL Workbench editor background color? It seems to always be white. I am using Workbench version 6.3.7.

Beware: There are other Stack posts out there with descriptors on how to do this, but the ones I tried didn't work. And in fact, some instructions are obsolete and no longer have the XML style elements that previous versions had.

I am looking in code_editor.xml (on my PC this lives here: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\data), and I see interesting sections such as:

```
<style id="1" fore-color="#008C3A" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT -->
<style id="2" fore-color="#008C3A" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE -->
<style id="21" fore-color="#F77B09" back-color="#F0F0F0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND -->

<style id="3" fore-color="#A58E37" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE -->
<style id="4" fore-color="#A58E37" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE -->
<style id="5" fore-color="#A58E37" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE -->

<style id="6" fore-color="#000000" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER -->
<style id="12" fore-color="#FF0000" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING -->
<style id="13" fore-color="#FF0000" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING -->

<style id="7" fore-color="#0101BD" bold="Yes" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD -->
<style id="8" fore-color="#0101BD" bold="Yes"/> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD -->
<style id="15" fore-color="#0101BD" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION -->
<style id="10" fore-color="#C04000" bold="Yes" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD -->
<style id="14" bold="Yes" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR -->

<style id="16" fore-color="#000000" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER -->
<style id="17" fore-color="#7D5A27" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER -->

<style id="22" fore-color="#FFFFFF" back-color="#A0A0A0" bold="Yes" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER -->

<style id="18" fore-color="#007F00" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1 -->

<!-- All styles again in their variant in a hidden command (with a 0x40 offset). -->
<style id="65" fore-color="#A0A0A0" back-color="#F0F0F0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT -->
<style id="66" fore-color="#A0A0A0" back-color="#F0F0F0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE -->

<style id="67" fore-color="#A58E37" back-color="#F0F0F0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE -->
<style id="68" fore-color="#A58E37" back-color="#F0F0F0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE -->
<style id="69" fore-color="#A58E37" back-color="#F0F0F0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE -->

<style id="70" fore-color="#F0A030" back-color="#F0F0F0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER -->
<style id="76" fore-color="#209F20" back-color="#F0F0F0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING -->
<style id="77" fore-color="#6D4A27" back-color="#F0F0F0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING -->

<style id="71" fore-color="#007FBF" back-color="#F0F0F0" bold="Yes" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD -->
<style id="72" fore-color="#007FBF" back-color="#F0F0F0" bold="Yes"/> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD -->
<style id="79" fore-color="#C040C0" back-color="#F0F0F0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION -->
<style id="74" fore-color="#C04000" back-color="#F0F0F0" bold="Yes" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD -->
<style id="78" back-color="#F0F0F0" bold="Yes" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR -->

<style id="80" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#F0F0F0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER -->
<style id="81" fore-color="#7D5A27" back-color="#F0F0F0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER -->

<style id="86" fore-color="#FFFFFF" back-color="#A0A0A0" bold="Yes" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER -->

<style id="82" fore-color="#007F00" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1 -->
```

But I can't figure out which of these (if any) will simply change the query editor background color. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The editor uses Scintilla and is configured through the file data/code_editor.xml as you guessed.

This file is composed of languages and for every language the styles have to be defined.

To change the text background use id 32 (STYLE_DEFAULT)

Example:
`<style id="32" back-color="#000000" /> <!-- STYLE_DEFAULT -->`

Line numbers background, on the left, can be customized through id 33 (STYLE_LINENUMBER)

The other styles id are for different keywords (described on code_editor.xml comments). For example: Comments background can be changed by adding `back-color` to id 1 and 2 on language SCLEX_MYSQL.

This has to be done for every language you want to customize.

As far as I know there is no way to change the default globally.

### References

- [Scintilla FAQ](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEFAQ.html#BlackBackground)
- [Scintilla Docs](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#StyleDefinition)

Comment: mabagu, there was no element in my `code_editor.xml` with an id of 32, so I added it and it worked. Nice! But the background color of all the lines containing text (not line numbers) is still white. How can I change all those? I tried changing the back-color hex codes of all I could find, but that did nothing; no change.

Comment: The background color of all the lines containing text (not line numbers) was still white. So I added back-color="#E3DDBF" on every single element, and that colorized 99% of the text line space as desired. BUT I still have white background behind special chars like *, =, %, etc. Any idea how to change those? (Why does Workbench make this so difficult?)

Comment: id 14 (SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR) is working for me to change the background on those special chars

Answer (score 7):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32055190/8328522) but I changed it so it works in MySQL Workbench 8.0 on Windows 10.
Not needed for MacOS since it has integrated Darkmode afaik.

Copy the following into `code_editor.xml` at the end in `<language name="SCLEX_MYSQL">`. You'll find this file under `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\data` or wherever you have Workbench installed.

```
<style id= "0" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DEFAULT                  -->
<style id= "1" fore-color-light="#999999" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT                  -->
<style id= "2" fore-color-light="#999999" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE              -->
<style id= "3" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE                 -->
<style id= "4" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE           -->
<style id= "5" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE      -->
<style id= "6" fore-color-light="#FF8080" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER                   -->
<style id= "7" fore-color-light="#7AAAD7" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD             -->
<style id= "8" fore-color-light="#7AAAD7" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD                  -->
<style id= "9" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DATABASEOBJECT           -->
<style id="10" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD         -->
<style id="11" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_STRING                   -->
<style id="12" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING                 -->
<style id="13" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING                 -->
<style id="14" fore-color-light="#FFBB80" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR                 -->
<style id="15" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION                 -->
<style id="16" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER               -->
<style id="17" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER         -->
<style id="18" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1                    -->
<style id="19" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER2                    -->
<style id="20" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER3                    -->
<style id="21" fore-color-light="#FFBB80" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND            -->
<style id="22" fore-color-light="#909090" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER              -->

<!-- These two are for scintilla globally. -->
<style id="32" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#2A2A2A" bold="No" />   <!-- STYLE_DEFAULT                      THIS IS THE ONE FOR THE BACKGROUND!!!!! -->
<style id="33" fore-color-light="#2A2A2A" back-color-light="#DDDDDD" bold="No" />   <!-- STYLE_LINENUMBER                   -->

<!-- All styles again in their variant in a hidden command (with a 0x40 offset). -->
<style id="65" fore-color-light="#999999" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT                  -->
<style id="66" fore-color-light="#999999" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE              -->
<style id="67" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE                 -->
<style id="68" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE           -->
<style id="69" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE      -->
<style id="70" fore-color-light="#FF8080" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER                   -->
<style id="71" fore-color-light="#7AAAD7" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD             -->
<style id="72" fore-color-light="#7AAAD7" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD                  -->
<style id="73" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DATABASEOBJECT           -->
<style id="74" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD         -->
<style id="75" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_STRING                   -->
<style id="76" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING                 -->
<style id="77" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING                 -->
<style id="78" fore-color-light="#FFBB80" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR                 -->
<style id="79" fore-color-light="#9B859D" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION                 -->
<style id="80" fore-color-light="#DDDDDD" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER               -->
<style id="81" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER         -->
<style id="82" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1                    -->
<style id="83" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER2                    -->
<style id="84" fore-color-light="#B9CB89" back-color-light="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER3                    -->
<style id="85" fore-color-light="#FFBB80" back-color-light="#909090" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND            -->
<style id="86" fore-color-light="#AAAAAA" back-color-light="#909090" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER              -->
```

You can also change the scheme to `Windows 7` under `Edit -> Preferences -> Fonts & Colors` in Workbench to make some extra elements a bit darker than default (for me at least).

Comment: This got my Query panels dark with white text as I type commands.  awesome.  Not to take away from the original question,  but how do we also get the GUI background to be dark as well (not just the Query panels).?

Comment: @klewis That is something I haven't managed to achieve myself, sorry.
I believe I remember reading that it takes those panel colours from some Windows defaults and that there was no (easy?) way to change those.

Comment: Worked great, now I won't feel like my eyes are on fire every time I have to use workbench :)